# Using Insert and Update statements in a related operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to insert a record to a table called `Payment` which has column `ID` as the primary key(Auto Increment) and then I want to get that `ID` to use in a `WHERE` clause of another  update statement.

```
var insertSatement = @"BEGIN INSERT INTO Payment (payment_type, reference, payment_date, total_records, total_amount) VALUES(@type, @reference, @date, @totalRecords, @totalAmount ) ";

var updateStatement = @"UPDATE SalaryTrans SET payment_id = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM Payment ORDER BY Payment.id) WHERE SalaryTrans.id = @paramID ";
```

These two statements could not be merged as the update is going to update multiple rows. It will update all matching rows of the `SalaryTrans` table. So I'm using a `foreach` loop.

```
//open connection, add parameters 

sqlCommand.CommandText = insertStatement;
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // This inserts...

foreach(PaymentInfo p in paymentList)
{
    paramID.value = p.id;
    sqlCommand.CommandText = updateStatement;
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

In the loop each time `"SELECT TOP 1 id..."` is also executed. To avoid it, is there a way to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the last updated `ID` from Payment table and use it in the loop?

Would there be a difference if I change update statement as follows in this context (performance wise) ?

```
DECLARE @ID INT = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM Payment ORDER BY Payment.id) 
UPDATE SalaryTrans SET payment_id = @ID WHERE SalaryTrans.id = 1
```

Or else should I separate this SELECT from the UPDATE to keep it outside the loop?

NOTE : My main concentration here is the performance factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can also try is, change your statement like below

```
var insertSatement = @"BEGIN INSERT INTO Payment (payment_type, reference, payment_date, total_records, total_amount) VALUES(@type, @reference, @date, @totalRecords, @totalAmount );  SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int) ";
```

Then in your excecute non query get the return value

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = insertStatement;
int id = (int) sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar(); // This inserts...
```

You can use the id in the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`

It will contain the latest value of the identity column from the newly inserted row

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: Should it be inside the insertStatement ?